# Running python code consumes GPU. why?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my python code for a model prediction.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import time


output_location='Desktop/result/'
 #load model
global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
model = load_model("newmodel.h5")
def Myfun():
        ecg = pd.read_csv('/Downloads/model.csv')
        X = ecg.iloc[:,1:42].values
        y = ecg.iloc[:,42].values

        from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
        encoder =  LabelEncoder()
        y1 = encoder.fit_transform(y)

        Y = pd.get_dummies(y1).values


        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        X_train,X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0) 
        t1= timer()
        with graph.as_default():
            prediction = model.predict(X_test[0:1])
            diff=timer()-t1
            class_labels_predicted = np.argmax(prediction)
            filename1=str(i)+"output.txt"
            newfile=output_location+filename1
            with open(str(newfile),'w',encoding = 'utf-8') as file:

                file.write(" takes %f seconds time.  predictedclass is %s \n" %(diff,class_labels_predicted))
        return class_labels_predicted

for i in range(1,100):
    Myfun()
```

My system GPU is of size 2GB. While running this code ,`nvidia-smi -l 2`  shows it consumes 1.8 GB of GPU. And 100 files are getting as a result. Soon after the task completes again GPU utilisation turns to 500MB. I have tensorflow and keras GPU version installed in my system. My Question is:

1. Why does this code runs on  GPU. Does the complete code uses GPU  or its only for importing libraries such as keras-gpu and tensorflow-gpu?

[image: This is the GPU consumption while starting the task]

[image: This shows GPU utilization (1.8 out of 2GB)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your code, you are using **Keras** and **Tensorflow**. From Keras [**F.A.Q.**](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-keras-on-gpu)

> If you are running on the **TensorFlow** or **CNTK** backends, your code will automatically run on GPU if any available GPU is detected.

Answer (score 1):

You can force Keras to run on CPU only

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```